# Can I get metrics on a tensorflow lite model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

I have been working on a complicated Keras model with a custom metric, and I recently converted it to tensorflow lite. The models are not exactly the same, and the outputs are different, however it is difficult to evaluate because the output is a tensor of size 128. Is there any way I can run my custom metric on this model? I have been using Tf 1.14. Below is some relevant code.

```
# compiler and train the model
model.save('model.h5')

# save the model in TFLite
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file('model.h5', custom_objects={'custom_metric': custom_metric})
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open('model.tflite', 'wb').write(tflite_model)

# run the model
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path='model.tflite')
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
input_dets = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_dets = interpreter.get_output_details()
input_shape = input_dets[0]['shape']
input_data = np.array(np.random.random_sample(input_shape), dtype=np.float32)
interpreter.set_tensor(input_dets[0]['index'], input_data)
interpreter.invoke()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The models are supposed to be different because the converter does graph transformations (such as fuse activation and fold batch norm) and the resulting graph is targeted in inference only scenarios.

To run metrics: the interpreter provides an API to get the output value (as an array):

```
output = interpreter.tensor(interpreter.get_output_details()[0]["index"])
```

Then you apply your metric on the output.

Comment: That's what I ended up having to do. Thank you!